# getting desired value from dictionary based on another value

Tags: python, dictionary

I have following output from a dictionary.

```
{'001': {'desc': 'Verify all commands.', 'result': 'P', 'name': '001', 'run_time': '00:00:30', 'start_time': '1382943624', 'end_time': '1382943654'}, 
'002': {'desc': 'Verify all commands.', 'result': 'F', 'name': '002', 'run_time': '00:00:30', 'start_time': '1382943624', 'end_time': '1382943654'}}
```

What I want is get `name` from it where `result` is `F`?
It will be helpful if someone can show me the way to achieve desired output.

Comment: The data you provided is not in proper format. Please check that.

Comment: I have corrected it, sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will the list of all the `names` where `result` is `F`

```
data = {'001': {'desc': 'Verify all commands.', 'result': 'P', 'name': '001', 'run_time': '00:00:30', 'start_time': '1382943624', 'end_time': '1382943654'}, 
'002': {'desc': 'Verify all commands.', 'result': 'F', 'name': '002', 'run_time': '00:00:30', 'start_time': '1382943624', 'end_time': '1382943654'},
'003': {'desc': 'Verify all commands.', 'result': 'F', 'name': '003', 'run_time': '00:00:30', 'start_time': '1382943624', 'end_time': '1382943654'}}

print [value["name"] for key, value in data.items() if value["result"] == "F"]
```

**Output**

```
['002', '003']
```

Comment: With this solution, I am getting `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'items'` error.

Comment: @npatel What is the format of the data? Can you please update the question with the proper format?

Comment: one extra bracket was there, sorry for that, I have updated the question now.

Comment: @npatel Please check my answer now. I changed the solution.

Answer (score 2):

Iterate over `dict.values`:

```
for v in my_dict.values():
   if v['result'] == 'F':
      print v['name']
```

**Demo:**

```
my_dict = {'001': {'desc': 'Verify all commands.', 'result': 'P', 'name': '001','run_time': '00:00:30', 'start_time': '1382943624', 'end_time': '1382943654'},
           '002': {'desc': 'Verify all commands.', 'result': 'F', 'name': '002', 'run_time': '00:00:30', 'start_time': '1382943624', 'end_time': '1382943654'}          }
for v in my_dict.values():
   if v['result'] == 'F':
      print v['name']
```

**output:**

```
002
```